# How to store post values of page 1 form in database when user submits in page 2?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

There are two pages. IN page 1 user enters a number and accordingly the data is fetched from db. In page 2 the user performs some action on data and presses submit in page2 then the id or the value submitted by the user in the first page is to be stored with data changed in page 2.I should store the changed data i page 2 with id in page1. I am unable to store the input of page one. I am new to php. Here is the code

Page 1:

```
<form name="VAL" action="ty.php" method="POST">
<?php
echo  "<input type=\"number\" name=\"j\" value=\"j\"class=\"input\" min=\"1\" max =\"2000\">                  
echo  "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit1\" value=\"choice1\"class=\"button\">         

?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
 $ytr=$_post['j'];//The value of number entered by user in page 1 this is not saving in db
  $wer=$_POST['hi'];
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'&& $_POST['submit2']=='choice2')
 {
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

 if (!$con){
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("ram", $con);
$sqlCmd = sprintf("INSERT INTO outp (tweet,Mtweet) VALUES ('%s','%s')", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($ytr),
    mysql_real_escape_string($wer));
mysql_query($sqlCmd);
mysql_close($con);
    }
?>`
```

Comment: I am not really getting what you're trying to do.

Comment: On the first submit, you can try to save the first 2 inputs in either session or save them in hidden input on page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  SESSION variable of php which stores data which is accessible throughout the application.